# Maven goal running from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

When I run `mvn compile` from command line, it builds using `pom.xml`. But when I try to run it within Eclipse (by using m2eclipse plugin), when I right click on the `pom.xml` and run as maven build, it asks for a goal. I am new to Maven and want to run it through Eclipse. So why doesn't it ask for anything when running from command line? Is there a default goal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a default goal, but what it is depends on the project, and can be explicitly defined.

See the [BaseBuild Element Set](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element) (the default goal is `install`) as well as the rest of that page for further information. IIRC you can define a default goal for m2eclipse, although I haven't used it in some time.

There's also a setting to define a goal to be run when a source directory is updated:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/preferences.html

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. But one question: So does maven install all the required jar files from the internet? Where does it add these? I built and installed successfully in eclipse by your help. Now I am getting about 100 errors for missing jar files.

Comment: @Sara **Errors:** If you're getting unresolved dependency errors there's likely something missing in either the pom file, or something funky with the m2eclipse setup. If you get the errors when *running*, outside of Eclipse, it's because you haven't defined the correct classpath. **Theory:** Yes, one of Maven's primary functions is to resolve transitive dependencies and download them automatically. By default your local repository is in your home directory, under `.m2/repository`.